# single node ejabberd on kubernetes -ejabberdctl status shows node down

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ejabberd

I'm trying to deploy ejabberd docker image in kubernetes with the following folders are mounted from a persistent volume,

1. /home/ejabberd/logs
2. /home/ejabberd/conf
3. /home/ejabberd/database

populated the database,and conf directory with our configuration files and the database folder

from the docker image  using an init container .Upon setting the permissions, we could able to

start the ejabberd service , the logs says that the services (on ports 5222,5269,5280) are ready .

when I check the xmpp server status in the container using " ejabberdctl status "  , the output says "node down"

```
===========ejabberd.log===================================================
2020-12-16 09:18:58.477630+00:00 [info] <0.3406.0>@mod_mqtt:init_topic_cache/2:611 Building MQTT cache for mydomain this may take a while

2020-12-16 09:18:59.087380+00:00 [info] <0.483.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:create/2:267 Creating Mnesia ram table 'bytestream'

2020-12-16 09:19:01.193203+00:00 [info] <0.126.0>@ejabberd_cluster_mnesia:wait_for_sync/1:123 Waiting for Mnesia synchronization to complete

2020-12-16 09:19:02.401537+00:00 [info] <0.126.0>@ejabberd_app:start/2:62 ejabberd 20.4.0 is started in the node 'ejabberd@mydomain' in 49.77s

2020-12-16 09:19:02.403414+00:00 [info] <0.601.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5222 for ejabberd_c2s

2020-12-16 09:19:02.403479+00:00 [info] <0.602.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5269 for ejabberd_s2s_in

2020-12-16 09:19:02.403956+00:00 [info] <0.603.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TLS connections at [::]:5443 for ejabberd_http

2020-12-16 09:19:02.403999+00:00 [info] <0.604.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:5280 for ejabberd_http

2020-12-16 09:19:02.404098+00:00 [info] <0.605.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TCP connections at [::]:1883 for mod_mqtt

2020-12-16 09:19:02.404345+00:00 [info] <0.3418.0>@ejabberd_listener:init/4:159 Start accepting TCP connections at 10.42.8.15:7777 for mod_proxy65_stream

========================================ejabberdctl status===========================

~ $ ./bin/ejabberdctl status

Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@mydomain': nodedown
Commands to start an ejabberd node:

  start  -    Start an ejabberd node in server mode

  debug  -    Attach an interactive Erlang shell to a running ejabberd node

  iexdebug -  Attach an interactive Elixir shell to a running ejabberd node

  live    -   Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode

  iexlive  -  Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode, within an Elixir shell

  foreground - Start an ejabberd node in server mode (attached)

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:

  --config-dir dir   Config ejabberd:    /home/ejabberd/conf

  --config file      Config ejabberd:    /home/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml

  --ctl-config file  Config ejabberdctl: /home/ejabberd/conf/ejabberdctl.cfg

  --logs dir         Directory for logs: /home/ejabberd/logs

  --spool dir        Database spool dir: /home/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@mydomain

  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@mydomain
```

If anyone has tried ejabberd on kubernetes, Please share your thought on this issue

Thanks in advance